# Create a new list with values other than a property of the class of the list type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `Customers` with `Id` and `Name` properties. After to create a `Customers` list, I want a new `customer` list that has no name repeated, that is, Customers.Name must be unique. My current output:

```
Gustavo
Gabriel
Mariza
Sandro
Gustavo
Gabriel
Lilian
Sandro
```

Output expected:

```
Gustavo
Gabriel
Mariza
Sandro
Lilian
```

I try this, but I've been making an error related to type conversion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SelectDistinct
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gustavo"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gabriel"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Mariza"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Sandro"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gustavo"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gabriel"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Lilian"));
            customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Sandro"));

            customers = customers.Select(x => x.Name.Distinct());

            customers.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            });
        }

        public class Customers
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Customers(int id, string name)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) method with comparer

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - OP is using `Distinct`, just not correctly for what they want.

Comment: customers2 was a typo

Comment: It can be done `GroupBy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) gives you an expected result

```cs
var result = customers
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
result.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name));
```

Output will be the following

```
Gustavo
Gabriel
Mariza
Sandro
Lilian
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it does not my code (deleted) did generate a `IEnumerable<string>` and the code of @Pavel does create a `List<Customer>` which OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There's many errors in the code you posted.

The first thing that I noticed is the wrong placement of `.Distinct()`. You've placed it inside the select and after the `Name` variable, which isn't logical.

The second thing is, you're trying to assign `customers.Select(x => x.Name.Distinct())` - which is of type `IEnumerable<char>` - to `customers` variable which is of type `List<Customers>`.

Now, to achieve what you're looking for, you have to correctly use the `Distinct` extension and to assign the result to the correct variable.

Here's your fully working code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gustavo"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gabriel"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Mariza"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Sandro"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gustavo"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Gabriel"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Lilian"));
    customers.Add(new Customers(0, "Sandro"));

    IEnumerable<string> distinctNames = customers.Select(x=>x.Name).Distinct();

    distinctNames.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customers(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: In fact, as I said in the statement, the final list has to be a list of customers and not strings. I already edited customers2, it was a typo.

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo Well, I was writing my answer before your edit/statements. To achieve what you're looking for you need to override the Equals function, and if I am not mistaken the GetHashCode also.

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` method uses default equality comparer.
You need to overload the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to work correctly.

```
public class Customers
{
    // your code here

    public override string ToString() => Id + " " + Name;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Customers customers &&
                Id == customers.Id &&
                Name == customers.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = -1919740922;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + Id.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Name);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```